# Add '%' to string for SQL search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

At the moment i have a textbox and a button and i can read the textbox fine and it searches the databse for say "apple"

but if there is a result called "red apple" it will not return it.

I have tried

```
string getTheBox = (this.searchBox.Text);

string request = "%" +  getTheBox + "%";
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. This is with "request" being the string variable.

EDIT to include the SQL request part

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT Recipe_Name FROM New_Recipe WHERE      [ingredient1]=@request

   SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(newParameter("request",System.TypeCode.String));
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["request"].DefaultValue = request;
```

Comment: You should probably show your database access code as that's the piece that really matters.

Comment: Can you include the code that *uses* `request`?

Comment: Read this once : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adding of % is correct, but you need to change your sql query

you need to use the [LIKE operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

for example THE QUERY could be

```
"SELECT Recipe_Name FROM New_Recipe WHERE ingredient1 LIKE @request"
```

and your code

```
   string request = "%" +  getTheBox + "%";
   string sqlText = "SELECT Recipe_Name FROM New_Recipe WHERE ingredient1 LIKE @request";
   using(SqlConnection cn = GetSqlConnection())
   {
       cn.Open();
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, cm);
       {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@request", request);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
             ......
            }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please post your SQL query too.  Perhaps you need to change `WHERE FruitName = @FruitName` to `WHERE FruitName LIKE @FruitName`

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible idea, as anyone can run sql injection. You probably want something akin to
[Sqlcommand.Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx)

As it will let you set safer arguements. And have two words.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a few helper functions to add like to my queries depending on what I need done.

```
public List<T> GetRecipesThatContain<T>(string ingredient)
{
    const string commandText = "SELECT Recipe_Name FROM New_Recipe WHERE ingredient1 LIKE @SearchTerm";
    var searchTerm = Contains(ingredient);

    using(var connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();

        using(var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", searchTerm);

            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var results = new List<T>();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    // Get results
                    // results.Add(result);
                }

                return results;
            }
        }
    }
}

private string StartsWith(string searchTerm)
{
    return string.Format("{0}%", searchTerm);
}

private string EndsWith(string searchTerm)
{
    return string.Format("%{0}", searchTerm);
}

private string Contains(string searchTerm)
{
    return string.Format("%{0}%", searchTerm);
}
```